# Getting an incorrect output for e^x function I made for class, and getting the wrong number of terms

Tags: c, math, calculus

So for my Intro to computer programming class we have to write 3 separate functions, one to calculate factorials, one to calculate powers (x^n), and one to calculate the number of terms of the taylor series with the given error approximation. Everytime I run my program, it prints that Nterms=1, instead of like 100, 300, 1000, etc.

It's probably a simple error in my loop, but I can't locate it. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double power(float A, int B)
{
    double sum=1.00;
    int nterms=1;

    while ( nterms <= B && B > 0) 
    {
        sum = A*sum;
        nterms++;
    }

    return sum; 
}

double factorial(int b)
{
    double fact=1.00;

    while (b >= 2) 
    {
        fact = b*(b-1)*fact;
        b = b-2;
    }

    return fact;    
}

int Terms(float X, float a)
{
    int N=1,l;
    double L,R;



    while (L < a && a <= R)
    {
        l=N+1;
        L= (power(X,l)/(factorial(l)));
        R= (power(X,N)/(factorial(N)));
        N++;
    }

    return N;
}

int main()
{

    float x, delta; 
    double sum=0.00, term=0.00;
    int n, Nterms;


    printf("Please enter a decimal number. x=");
    scanf("%f",&x);
    printf("Please enter an another number. delta=");
    scanf("%f",&delta);


    Nterms=Terms(x,delta);
    printf("Nterms=%d\n",Nterms);

    for(n=0;n<Nterms;n++)
    {
         if( n==0 || n==1 )
        {
            sum = 1 + x;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum + term;
            term = (power(x,n))/(factorial(n));
        }   
    }

    printf("The approximation for e^(%f)=%.4f",x,sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this `c` code? You have tagged it as `basic`, which refers to the BASIC programming language.

Comment: I wasn't aware that was a programming language, whoops

Comment: Please explain exactly what happens why in the NTerms function. There are uninitialized variables (use -Wall while compiling). It is inconceivable what the computation is to achieve. Please check your understanding of the factorial function.

Comment: @LutzL I used -Wall and I didn't get any error messages. My Nterms function was supposed to continue adding 1 to n, until the given accuracy is not greater than the left error bound and less than the right error bound.

Comment: The `power` function seems fine. `factorial` works; it just performs two multiplications every loop iteration (which is fine since multiplying by 1 does nothing). You haven't initialized `L` and `R` in your `Terms` function so there's no telling what it will do.

Comment: Just so you know, a 32-bit `int` is only good for factorials up to 12. Anything beyond 12 factorial will overflow an `int`. Also, when doing math problems, you should use `double` for everything, because `float` only has 6 or 7 digits of precision. Even `double` may not have enough precision for what you're doing, but it's the best you can get without a high precision math library.

Comment: @eigenchris I rearranged it and first defined L as equal to power/factorial, and R as power/factorial, however I still get an Nterms value of 1.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you! I swapped them for doubles

Comment: Can you explain in greater detail what `L` and `R` are for? I notice `L` doesn't change in your `while` loop. Is `R` the size of the smallest term in the series, since you want `delta`  to be greater than `R`? What value of `delta` are you testing your program with?

Comment: The formula that is usually used to calculate the error called "Taylor Inequality." Where L< error < R , and L = (x^(n+1)) /(n+1)! and                  R = x^(n) / (n)!.

Comment: @eigenchris And I usually make delta .01, .001, or .0001. It doesnt work for any of them though.

Comment: Clearly your code has diverged from what you posted.  Would be best if you edited the post to bring it up to date.

Comment: `factorial` wil exceed the precision of `double` pretty early on; this approach won't be viable if you intend going as deep as `100`

Answer (score 1):

That your `Terms` function always returns 1 means that N never changes from its initial value, which means that you never enter the while loop

```
while (L < a && a <= R)
```

which means that the condition is never satisfied.

I suggest stepping through, noting what you think L and R ought to be when you should require more terms, and checking what they actually are when you get there without initializing them.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is the only problem, but your terms function should probably use a bottom tested loop so that L and R are at least defined.  Also, you don't really need to test both L and R as you know L failed to meet the R criteria on the previous iteration.  Something like:

```
int Terms(float X, float a)
{
    int N=0;
    double R;

    do {
        N++;
        R = (power(X,N)/(factorial(N)));
    } while (a <= R)

    return N;
}
```